# Exit protractor spec without failure

Tags: protractor

Is there a way I can stop protractor from executing more tests in a spec even if there was no failure in the previous tests?

```
> describe('tests', function () {
>         it('should exit', function () {
>           protractor.stop(); <---- is there a way to prevent executing more tests?
>         });
>         it('should not run', function () {
>           expect(something).toBeTruthy();
>         });
>       });
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe using an fit ( focused it ) block or a jasmine plugin like https://github.com/Updater/jasmine-fail-fast is what you are looking for?